# Touchpad not recognized on new Ultrabook

Tags: laptop, 14.04, touchpad, samsung

I have a new Samsung ATIV Book 9 2014 Edition (930X5J-K01) and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it. The touchpad is not working at all. There is no cursor visible but an external USB mouse is working fine.

After upgrading the kernel to 3.15 RC2, an UNKNOWN input device is detected. But again, no mouse cursor appears. I tried many approaches to get the touchpad working, but nothing worked. Using an older version of Ubuntu, or another Linux dirso doesn't work too.

I uploaded additional debugging information, where you can see the new detected input device (**ATML3000**). Windows detects the Touchpad as **HID\ATML3000&COL01\5&1579C925&0&0000**

Output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

- Kernel 3.13 [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/HVe9zdTd)
- Kernel 3.15 RC2 [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/1hAv5fN2)

`dmesg` Output:

- Kernel 3.13 [Click here](http://pastebin.com/Xuk8sxcA)
- Kernel 3.15 RC2 [Click here](http://pastebin.com/X3Zw6tPW)

Content of `Xorg.0.log`

- Kernel 3.13 [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/8JUjrhUn)
- Kernel 3.15 [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/yNhcXkub)

Output of `sudo lshw`

- Kernel 3.13 [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/jmhfiKJn)
- Kernel 3.15 RC2 [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/4nhWu6T3)

I used [HID Replay](http://bentiss.github.io/hid-replay-docs/) to check that the device is actually working, to see the generated output during some gestures [Click here](http://pastebin.com/psFudPsp).

Comment: Have you fully updated **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**, since installing? *(14.04 **beta** had this issue.)*

Comment: Can you identify the exact hardware (in **`sudo lshw`** output) for the touchpad device?

Comment: I use a fresh installation of 14.04 LTS. The output of `sudo lshw` does not show the Touchpad. I added the complete output above.

Comment: Is **14.04 LTS** updated, after install? **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**, followed by **`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`**

Comment: Yes, it is completely updated.

Comment: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY3NjM This might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an upstream problem from the 3.15-rc kernel. A patch has been submitted here:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4096321/

3.15 final should not contain the bug.

oh, and this is *not* a conflict with i2c_hid.

Comment: *Does this solve the issue?* Still seeing in fully patched **14.04 LTS 32-bit**.

Answer (score 1):

### My experience:

This is *possibly* a *race condition* on cold startup, and exists under 13.04 and 13.10 as well.

This occurred for me on two *HP Mini 210* netbooks, with new installs of Ubuntu **14.04 LTS beta**. But once touchpad started working, it has not re-occurred. *I thought it was an update which fixed issue, but it may have been something else.*

### **UPDATE:** (03-May-2014)

Still occurs on *HP Mini 210* netbook (at **cold start**), with Ubuntu **14.04 LTS** 32-bit (fully updated).

But self corrects after several minutes (**362 seconds**):

```
user01@HP-Mini-210-1036VU:~$ dmesg | grep -e mouse -e Mouse
[    1.300793] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[  362.023854] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.4, id: 0x1e0b1, caps: 0xd04773/0xe40000/0x5a0400, board id: 3655, fw id: 627142
```

On re-start, no longer occurs: (starts in only **13 seconds**)

```
user01@HP-Mini-210-1036VU:~$ dmesg | grep -e mouse -e Mouse
[    1.300641] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[   13.205310] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.4, id: 0x1e0b1, caps: 0xd04773/0xe40000/0x5a0400, board id: 3655, fw id: 627142
```

---

### For your Samsung laptop:

Try restarting laptop, after it has been running for 5+ minutes.

Wait for further 3-4 minutes (after re-start) and check output of **dmesg**:

```
dmesg | grep -e mouse -e Mouse
```

### OR

Try restarting the driver (5+ minutes after laptop started)

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

OR possibly (from: [Samsung 305u notebook touchpad not working in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362037/samsung-305u-notebook-touchpad-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10))

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

---

### **UPDATE:** (later, on 03-May-2104)

This is *still* likely the root cause: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1218973

Conflict between **i2c_hid** (*old-school* PS/2 / serial driver), and developments to support multi-touch displays.

***However ..***

Here is an *old* fix for the same issue, which you should try.

from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1423273&p=8927602#post8927602

( actually from: http://www.linlap.com/acer_aspire_5542g advice from *Juan Peròn* )

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change line: **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash”** to add: '**i8042.nomux**'.

ie.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash i8042.nomux”
```

Then update:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, but that did not work. dmesg gives the following output http://pastebin.com/a9zswUKm

Comment: Found this (*a clue*): https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74241 ***What kernel are you running?***

Comment: I use 3.15 RC2 now. I'll try 3.14 next, thank you for the link!

Comment: Thank you so much for your greate effort. I tried to understand the reported bugs, installed serveral new kernel modules and kernel versions, but non of them worked.

Comment: I added more logfile for Kernel 3.15 RC2.

Comment: This appears to be a **power-management** and **startup** related (see update above).

Comment: Added another possible fix.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/548725/touchpad-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04