# Followup question: How to get fix for trackpad bug from 3.15 kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, touchpad, samsung, trackpad

This is a followup question to [Touchpad not recognized on new Ultrabook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455516/)

In that question, asker had trouble with the trackpad not working on Samsung ATIV Book 9 2014 Edition (NP930X5J/NP940X5J) with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. (I am having the same exact issue.) The accepted answer said that it is a kernel bug and that the final version of 3.15 kernel will contain the fix. The answerer linked to kernel bug report https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4096321/

I read news that the stable 3.15 kernel was released a few days ago on 8-Jun-2014. I am hopeful that it has the fix for this issue!

Question 1: Does the stable 3.15 kernel indeed contain the fix (kernel patch 4096321)?

Question 2: What is the next Ubuntu release that will contain this kernel (and hence contain the fix that I need)?

Question 3: If I can't bear to wait until the next Ubuntu release, then what is the next Ubuntu test kernel (I'm assuming from kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D but correct me if I'm wrong) that would have the fix?

Question 4: If I want to install the test kernel that is the answer to question 3, can I do that safely without leaving 14.04 LTS? I really want to stay on an LTS version of Ubuntu. I'm not looking to upgrade Ubuntu every 6 months. I just want to make my trackpad work and then not make any further changes to my system for a few years (except automated updates, of course).

Thanks in advance!

PS. I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu so forgive me if some of my questions are badly asked.

### Update:

Thanks for the answers. I finally upgraded the kernel to one of the stable 3.15 versions from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) (delay was mostly due to me being afraid of the unknown, particularly of breaking my computer). I'm half-happy to report that the touchpad now half-works. Specifically, it works after computer startup, but stops working after suspend+resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions: At the bottom of the [patch page you linked](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4096321/) it says that the patch is present in 3.15. Kernel version 3.15 [has been released](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-utopic/COMMIT), and version 3.16 will be the default kernel [in Utopic Unicorn](http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn-based-on-kernel-3-16-will-be-officially-released-on-the-23rd-of-october-2014/). If you want to install kernel 3.15 in Ubuntu 14.04, download the appropriate packages ([what are they?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Installing_upstream_kernels)) from the [mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-utopic/) or install them [using apt and ppa technology](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa), which I recommend, because then you keep your kernel updated. Be aware that other issues may come up when you install a newer kernel.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is queued for 3.15, so it should be present in that version.
2. Utopic will get kernel 3.15.
3. I think you'll have to request the fix be backported to the 3.12 kernel. As part of Ubuntu policy, kernel versions remain the same on a given release.
4. Because this is an LTS release, you'll be able to use newer kernels in Trusty. If the 12.04.x schedule on [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) page is to be followed, you'll get 3.15 about 3 months after Utopic is released.