# Samsung series 9, touchpad does not work after suspend, Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: touchpad, suspend, samsung

I got a brand-new Samsung series 9 (exact reference is: NP940X5J-K02US).  Because of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482049/followup-question-how-to-get-fix-for-trackpad-bug-from-3-15-kernel), mentioning it required at least a kernel 3.15, I waited a couple of weeks for Ubuntu 14.10 to be released.

The touchpad works out of the box, except that it does not respond at all after a suspend.  I have no idea how I can investigate any further.

Does anyone knows how to fix it, or at least how to provide the community with more information about the problem?  I could leave with executing a command every time after a suspend.

Comment: Try gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 3.18 kernel, you can get it [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) for ubuntu 14.10.