# Laptop touchpad is not working

Tags: drivers, 14.04, laptop, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but it's not recognizing touchpad of laptop. What can be caused to this?

Here some outputs:

```
xinput list
```

output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G RX                                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

```
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

output:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/455516/touchpad-not-recognized-on-new-ultrabook