# Touchpad not Working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, dell, touchpad

I am using Dell Inspiron 3521 model.
Ever since I installed ubuntu, my touchpad (Synaptic) is not working.
However an external mouse is working fine.
On running command "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" , touchpad is not being shown up!
I have tried installing all the drivers, updating the kernel and creating psmouse.conf file too (I got these solutions from internet).
Still the problem persists.
Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can test if your touchpad works with an ubuntu 14.10 Live-CD. In this case you need the new kernel 3.16 with the new Synaptic drivers.

So I see three possibilities:

1. you can update your kernel in ubuntu 14.04 from 3.13 to 3.16 on your own (details: google.com)
2. you can wait till the kernel 3.16 is integrated in ubuntu 14.04 by the ubuntu team (february 2015?)
3. or you can update to ubuntu 14.10

good luck!