# Synaptics driver does not load in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xorg, synaptics

I have encountered a strange problem after upgrading my kernel in ubuntu 14.04, mainly the touchpad scrolling stopped working. After spending some time on debuging I came to a conclusion that synaptics driver is not loaded. This are the clues that make me think so:

1) touchpad is detected

```
$ xinput -l
...
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]`
```

2) no trace of 'synaptics' driver in Xorg.0.log:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep synaptics
```

is empty

3) finally in the same log file I found line which states:

```
[    34.046] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
```

which is quite straightforward. I have tried purging and reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` with no good effect. Also config file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf look OK to me as it contains:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be 
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
EndSection
```

what may be a little strange is that my system possesses copy of this file located in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`

of course I am not able to change anything from graphical mode (**Settings->Mouse and Touchpad**) as there are no options there.

Does anyone have an idea why does my system ignore config file 50-synaptics.conf and uses evdev as driver?

EDIT: kernel I use now is 3.13.0-43-generic. last time the touchpad worked correctly was with 3.13.0-29-generic

Comment: Same issue (unresolved) as: http://askubuntu.com/questions/455516/touchpad-not-recognized-on-new-ultrabook

Comment: Possible *root cause* / solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/548725/touchpad-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: if I understood correctly both of those problems affect kernels 3.15-RC. my system uses 3.13.0-43-generic kernels from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: **More correctly:** there is an up-stream fix, that may not arrive **until** 3.16 is released. *You may need to try a newer/beta kernel.*